# How can I install this widget on elementary?

Tags: software-installation, conky

[image: Google Weather with system monitor]
<sub>(source: [blogspot.com](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-XLbj_QTCPzE/VDaOisp6zEI/AAAAAAAABNs/Se7mTfzUbWo/s1600/elementary_os.png))</sub>

I want to install a system monitor which looks something like the one in the image.

Comment: Have your issue been resolved by the answer or do you need more detailed one?

Answer (score 5):

It's a conky with Google Now theme.

You want to install `conky` and `conky-manager` and then [download](http://satya164.deviantart.com/art/Conky-Google-Now-366545753) the theme.

Unpack the downloaded archive with theme into `~/.config` (which is a hidden folder in your home folder - you can unhide it by pressing `ctrl+H` in your file manager). Now the theme should show up in conky manager.

Note: the `conky-manager` is not in the elementary repos and needs to be installed from developer's PPA - `ppa:teejee2008/ppa`.

Comment: I think I gave you enough info for more research (I'm busy now) but if you need more elaborate answer (e.g. you're a newbie), just let me know and I'll try to improve it. I know conky isn't the easiest thing to setup.

Comment: could you explain how to add the downloaded theme?

Comment: Try unpacking the downloaded theme and copying the resulting folder into ~/.conky (it is a hidden folder in your home folder, to unhide it press ctrl+H in your file manager) - you should be then able to see it in conky manager. If it still won't work, let me know and I will install conky and try it myself (I only installed conky for my sister and used one of the theme included in the conky manager (gotham), so I don't have it myself and don't remember all the steps).

Comment: Extracting into ~/.conky worked, thanks!

Comment: great, I'm glad I could help :) I'll update the answer